# Weblogic 8.1 - delta :447 ErrorMessage

Tags: deployment, weblogic8.x

Did anyone run into this error with weblogic 8.1 when trying to deploy an application?

[Deployer:149034]An exception occurred for task [Deployer:149026]Deploy application myApplication on myServer.: Delta :447 ErrorMessage :Unexpected Exception.

Answer (score 0):

it's been a long time since I last ran WebLogic 8.1.  You realize, of course, that the [current version is 10.3.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/overview/index.html)? (Or is it 11g - Oracle is so confusing with their release numbers.)  And that WebLogic 8.1 is at least two years past its retirement date?

You're correct - that message is obscure.  It's likely everyone has seen it and realized that they'd have to look elsewhere for the answer.  Sounds to me like you have a deployment/packaging/configuration error.  I'd look in the logs and the console for more details.